# Ubuntu 14.04 / apache 2.4 with php5-fpm via mod_proxy_fcgi return wrong chunked encoding

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php-fpm

Didn't see any reporting of this problem anywhere. When using Apache 2.4 with `php5-fpm` using `mod_proxy_fcgi`, chunked encoded content last empty block seems to be missing.

- Firefox and IE hang until connection times out.
- Chrome reports this error:

  ```
  net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
  ```
- `curl -vi --raw` gives this message :

  ```
  * transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
  * Closing connection 0
  curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
  ```

The problem shows up with a site using WordPress and this Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.ingenie.net
        DocumentRoot /srv/sites/test/www/
        FallbackResource /index.php
        ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:11001/srv/sites/test/www/$1"
        <Directory /srv/sites/test/www/>
                AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit Options
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

PHP-FPM pool is :

```
[default]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:11001
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 256
pm.start_servers = 15
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.status_path = /status
ping.path = /ping
slowlog = /var/log/apache2/php5-fpm-slow.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 60s
chdir = /
```

I don't know if this is specific to WordPress, but all WordPress sites on my server had the same problem and I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with a simple PHP site.

I made a test site with WordPress to see the problem: http://test.ingenie.net/

Currently I'm not really looking for help since I have a solution to this problem using `mod_fastcgi`, but I think other may have the same problem and it may help to find a bug related to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.